# Kubespray: [Errno 111] Connection refused>", "redirected": false, "status": -1, "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8080/healthz

Tags: kubernetes

I am new to Kubernetes and I am trying to deploy a Kubernetes cluster using Kubespray (https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/kubespray
)

When I run `ansible-playbook -bi inventory/inventory cluster.yml` it fails with:

> fatal: [kube-k8s-master-1]: FAILED! => {"attempts": 20, "changed":
>   false, "content": "", "failed": true, "msg": "Status code was not
>   [200]: Request failed: ", "redirected": false, "status": -1, "url":
>   "http ://127.0.0.1:8080/healthz"}

etcd service log:

> Oct 05 13:53:06 kube-k8s-master-1 systemd[1]: etcd.service: main
>   process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE Oct 05 13:53:11
>   kube-k8s-master-1 docker[32146]: etcd1 Oct 05 13:53:11
>   kube-k8s-master-1 systemd[1]: Unit etcd.service entered failed state.
>   Oct 05 13:53:11 kube-k8s-master-1 systemd[1]: etcd.service failed.

kubelet service log:

> Oct 05 13:56:02 kube-k8s-master-1 kubelet[19938]: E1005
>   13:56:02.500377   19938 reflector.go:190]
>   k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:408: Failed to list *v1.Node:
>   Get https://127.0.0.1:6443/api/v1/nodes?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3
>   Oct 05 13:56:03 kube-k8s-master-1 kubelet[19938]: W1005
>   13:56:03.190059   19938 container.go:352] Failed to create summary
>   reader for
>   "/docker/ce8dbd1a8edfbe6b604aab4f38eff406846b1cfc8858ba23e7db5cac36d2247d":
>   none of the resources are be Oct 05 13:56:03 kube-k8s-master-1
>   kubelet[19938]: E1005 13:56:03.497076   19938 reflector.go:190]
>   k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:46: Failed to list
>   *v1.Pod: Get https ://127.0.0.1:6443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.node Oct 05
>   13:56:03 kube-k8s-master-1 kubelet[19938]: E1005 13:56:03.499795
>   19938 reflector.go:190] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:400:
>   Failed to list *v1.Service: Get
>   https ://127.0.0.1:6443/api/v1/services?resourceVersion=0: dial Oct 05
>   13:56:03 kube-k8s-master-1 kubelet[19938]: E1005 13:56:03.500800
>   19938 reflector.go:190] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:408:
>   Failed to list *v1.Node: Get
>   https ://127.0.0.1:6443/api/v1/nodes?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3 Oct
>   05 13:56:04 kube-k8s-master-1 kubelet[19938]: W1005 13:56:04.155665
>   19938 cni.go:189] Unable to update cni config: No networks found in
>   /etc/cni/net.d Oct 05 13:56:04 kube-k8s-master-1 kubelet[19938]: E1005
>   13:56:04.155825   19938 kubelet.go:2136] Container runtime network not
>   ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker:
>   network plugin is not ready: cni config Oct 05 13:56:04
>   kube-k8s-master-1 kubelet[19938]: E1005 13:56:04.190285   19938
>   eviction_manager.go:238] eviction manager: unexpected err: failed
>   GetNode: node 'kube-k8s-master-1' not found

How can I fix this?

Comment: Where do you trying to install k8s (cloud provider or bare metal)? Can we see which data vars are you using?